# Should std::async respect thrown errors?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to understand how exceptions are handled asynchronously -- I have a webserver that contains a lambda handler for processing requests (uWebsockets) and it keeps crashing. To simulate the scenario I used std::async

```
void call(function<void()> fn) {
  std::async([&fn]{
    fn();
  });
}

int main() {
  try {
    call([](){
      throw std::runtime_error("Oops");
    });
  } catch (std::runtime_error &e) {
    cout<<"Caught the error"<<endl;
  }
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100000));
}
```

It seems that running the function inside std::async causes the runtime error to never execute ... the program just exits as if nothing happened... why is this the case?

Comment: Usually exceptions do not propagate automatically outside the thread. At least in most of my experience with it in different languages. It should be captured within it and you are responsible for providing a way to pass it on (return an error code or set a flag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take this step by step. Let's start with the [very definition of what `std::async` does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async). It:

> runs the function f asynchronously (potentially in a separate thread

The word "potentially" is a distraction here, but the point is that a ***different execution thread*** is going to be involved here. For all practical reasons, the function getting `std::async`-ed can, and on modern C++ implementations, it ***will*** run in a new execution thread.

The very reason for having different execution threads, in the first place, is that they are ***completely*** independent of their parent execution thread. Different execution threads must properly implement *sequencing* operations in order to mutually exchange information between themselves, in some form or fashion.

```
  try {

  } catch (std::runtime_error &e) {
    cout<<"Caught the error"<<endl;
  }
```

The concept of exceptions, and how `try` and `catch` relate to them, is introduced in your average C++ textbook by explaining how `try`/`catch` will catch exceptions that occur ***inside the `try`/`catch` block***. Once execution leaves the `try`/`catch` block, exception handling is no longer in effect, and no exception will be caught (unless execution is inside another `try`/`catch` block).

It may or may not be immediately clear that combining the concepts of execution threads and this typical explanation of exception handling, you must reach the inevitable conclusion that you can only catch exceptions thrown ***from the same execution thread***.

Additionally, in the shown code, there's absolutely nothing that even ***guarantees*** that the original execution thread will still be inside the `try`/`catch` block when the exception in the other execution thread gets thrown. In fact, it is more likely than not that the parent execution thread has left the original `try`/`catch` block and it's `sleep_for`-ing, when the exception gets thrown. You cannot catch exceptions any more, after leaving the `try`/`catch` block.

But even if the original execution thread is still inside the `try`/`catch` block this won't make any difference, because thrown exceptions can only be caught by the same execution thread, but the function that gets executed by `std::async` will be running in a completely different execution thread.

**Edit**:

```
std::async([&fn]{
```

This captures `fn` by reference. `fn` is a function parameter that goes out of scope and gets destroyed when the function returns, but there's no guarantee that the new execution thread will reference it before it does. This is immaterial, for the purposes of the mechanics of exception handling (and to how `std::async` itself handles thrown exceptions), but this needs to be fixed nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks this explains 99%. The one piece I still don't understand is why is the exception never thrown in the other execution thread? The program just exits with no runtime error shown... is this because runtime errors only kill the program if they happen on the main thread?

Comment: If you look up the specification of `std::async`, you will find an explanation of how it will catch any exception thrown by the thread function, and what it does with it (my answer applies despite of that). I have to note that the shown code exhibits undefined behavior, so pretty much everything goes out the window because of that. It captures the function object ***by reference*** which, of course, goes out of scope and gets destroyed without getting properly sequenced with the function call. You will need to fix this bug (by capturing by value) before actually testing exception handling.

Comment: Isn't the `future` returned from `async` paradoxically synchronous, i.e. its destructor waits for the asynchronous function to complete? Would this not make the given example code well-defined? The reason that no exception is thrown in the main thread is actually that the `future`'s value is never inquired.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you do not observe the exception in the main thread is that the value of the `future` that `async` returns is never inquired. If you extend your implementation of `call` like this:

```
void call(function<void()> fn) {
  std::async([&fn]{
    fn();
  }).get();    // .get() added here
}
```

then the exception is observed because the function waits for the result.

Even without this modification, `call` has well-defined behavior despite @SamVarshavchik's analysis because the `future` that `async` returns is special in a particular way: [its destructor waits for the function to complete](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) (see the Notes section there). That is, `call` does not return until the called thread has completed (thrown the exception).